# insert many records at a time mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I have a list of dictionaries (approximately 20.000 dictionaries):

```
lista=[{'a':1, 'b':'hello','c':'home'},{'a':2, 'b':'sass','c':'qwwqw'};{'a':3, 'b':'ded','c':'eded'}]
```

'a', 'b' and 'c' are the fields in a mysql table

What would be the best way to insert this list in my database? I have tried this but not sure if it is the best option...

```
for i in lista:
   cursor.execute("insert....", i.value())
```

Comment: write them into `csv` files and use mysql [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. [Start a transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)
2. Execute a bunch of INSERT statements.
3. Commit the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use one insert statement with multiple rows of data. I did it before. Here is a portion from the MySQL reference manual.

```
INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows.
To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed
within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:

INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Here is a link to that page.

```
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html
```